# How do i send Header value with webview url?

Tags: android

I develop and android app which has webview. I want to send header value with url. If it is possible any one help me to give the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
headers.put(header-key, header-value);
mWebView.loadUrl(your url, headers);
```

does this one helps? [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29)

Answer (score 3):

It is better to do that via HttpClient.