# missing webview headers on kitkat(?) and below

Tags: android, webview, http-headers

I am trying to attach headers on my webview requests Similar to below:

Taken from this answer: [How do i send Header value with webview url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314224/how-do-i-send-header-value-with-webview-url)

```
 Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
 headers.put(header-key, header-value);
 mWebView.loadUrl(your url, headers);
```

However, only on newer devices does it actually send the headers.

I have also overridden webview methods to re-attach headers on every request.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)               
    view.loadUrl(url, getExtraHeaders());
    return true;
}
```

Still the same issue, Kitkat and below do not send the headers. I just get **no headers** coming into my server.

From what I can gather, it may be a bug in WebView. But I cannot update it? As my device has webview built in.

I have also installed chrome to try and help. There must be a way to send headers in webview for older devices??