# Detecting Android & iOS Webviews

Tags: javascript, android, ios, iphone, webview

Is there any way to detect using Javascript only if I'm dealing with a user that came from ios/android and using our app (Webview)?

From what I collected so far, You can do it with PHP reading headers, or somewhat with detecting user-agents with Javascript, but I can't seem to get it all to work.

I need both android and iOS webviews detected. Any ideas guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can send custom HTTP headers to WebView using iOS and Android App. In your Website, you get this header in order to distinguish which is Android or iOS.

This is how you can [send headers to `WebView` using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12314496/2967645), [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12856169/2967645) and even how you can [get this using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/541463/2967645).